# Can Windows installer msi make the user full trust

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, full-trust

our applicaton is installing with windows installer. The things working fine but the application itself is full trusted and not allowing to run on the employee's computer with less level (not full trusted).
My question is that, is there any way to make the user full trusted for this application during the installation?
Can we make our windowos installer msi in this position to make the user as full trusted for this application?

Best Regards
Adnan

Comment: By being 'Full trusted', do you mean as it having administrator permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the correct manifest to your application, in this case it seems you will need `requireAdministrator`

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

Comment: yes i mean administrator level permission because the employees are getting security exceptions. The installation is running successfully but starting the application causing problem without full trust level.